# C program for secant method to find roots of polynomial

Tags: c, math

Here is the question:

Write a program to find the real roots of the following equation using the [**Secant method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method):

`f(x) = 23x^4 -13x^3 + 3x^2 - 5x + 38`.

Let `h = r(i) - r(i-1)`, where `r(i)` is the root computed in iteration `i` of your program. Your program should continue to refine its answer until `h < 10 - 3`. This value is known as the convergence criterion. Your program should print the final value of the root and the number of iterations required to compute it.

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double function ( double i );

int main ()
{
    double x_1, x_2, h_x, temp, a, b;

   int count = 0;

   printf("Enter first approximation: ");
   scanf("%lf", &x_1);

   printf("Enter second approximation: ");
   scanf("%lf", &x_2);

   a = function ( x_1 );
   b = function ( x_2 );

   h_x = x_2 - x_1;

   if ( h_x < 0 )
        {
           h_x = ( h_x < 0 )? - h_x: h_x;
        }

   while ( h_x >= ( 1.E-3 ) && count <= 999999999 )
   {
    a = function ( x_1 );
    b = function ( x_2 );
    temp = ( ( x_1 * b ) - ( x_2 * a ) / ( b - a ) );
    x_1 = x_2;
    x_2 = temp;

    printf("%lf\n", x_1);
    printf("%lf\n", x_2);

    count += 1;
    h_x = x_2 - x_1;

    if ( h_x < 0 )
    {
        h_x = ( h_x < 0 )? - h_x: h_x;
    }

}

printf("Final value of root is %lf\n", x_2);
printf("%d iterations were required to compute it\n", count);

return 0;
 }


 double function ( double i )
 {
     double result;

   result = ( 23 * i * i * i * i ) - ( 13 * i * i * i ) + ( 3 * i * i ) - ( 5 * i ) + 38;

   return result;
 }
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't work for any other input that is different from `0` and `1`.

I don't see what's the problem with my code though, I have added a code for absolute error, and the formula looks right to me. It isn't logical to me that with different initial guesses, the root returned is different, and just loops forever.

I would just like to know if it is a coding mistake, or a math error. Or is it that the roots oscillate? I just don't know what's wrong with my program. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing out `h_x` after each iteration? Other tips: why write `( 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.1 )` instead of just `1.E-3`? When you find that `h_x` is < 0, why recompute it rather than just `h_x = -h_x;` ? Hopefully the compiler can optimize function(), but you could use `y - 38 + (x * -5 + (x * 3 + ...));

Comment: I have edited the code above with some of your suggestions. However, it still does not work. I would like to know if this program works for complex roots, because the roots for this polynomial seem to be complex. Thanks!

Comment: No, with a method over the real numbers you will only find real roots. You might get results using Bairstows method since that finds quadratic factors, thus covers also pairs of complex conjugate roots. Or use the `complex double` data type, you get complex roots from real initial values using a phase shifted function `f(x)*exp(i*0.001*x)`.

Comment: Yes, it is very confusing. This is a homework problem, and he asked us to use the secant method for this. Thus, Bairstows method can't be used here. I have brought this up with the TA, and he would get back to me later. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your midpoint formula is off. It seems to be a mix of two variants of the formula. The formula close to the derivation as root of the secant line

```
y = f(x_2)+(x-x2) * (f(x2)-f(x1))/(x2-x1)
```

gives

```
x3 = x2 - f(x2)*(x2-x1)/(f(x2)-f(x1)).
```

Bringing everything into one fraction gives the equivalent

```
x3 = (x1*f(x2) -x2*f(x1)) / (f(x2)-f(x1)).
```

---

You get a shorter formula for the polynomial using the Newton-Horner trick,

```
f(x) = ((( 23 * x  -  13 ) * x + 3 ) * x -  5 ) * x + 38.
```

---

You should avoid the repeated computation of the same quantity, even if it does not have any noticeable effect here. Declare variables for the values `f(x1)` and `f(x2)`.

---

Use the absolute value function to compute absolute values. `hx = fabs(x2-x1)`. Or use `hx=(hx<0)?-hx:hx;` to avoid including `math.h`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have edited the code according to your suggestions (see above). However, now the output gives values like    -1.#IND00. And, also my TA said that the two initial roots must not be random and must be close to actual value of roots. I wonder how to find that actual roots if I'm writing a program to approximate it? Thanks again!

Comment: Of course, if there are no roots to find, your program will search indefinitely. Use WolframAlpha or specialized applets like http://www.akiti.ca/PolyRootRe.html to find that all roots are complex, `0.9382335836057213   +-   0.7594072313917729 i` and `-0.6556248879535475   +-   0.8391223634916823 i`.